# Iterate through list R

Tags: r, loops, concatenation

Ok, so I try to do the most basic operation, but it seems quite complicated with R.

What I would like to achieve is to iterate through a list.

To acces a particular value within this list, I just need to write:

```
list.data$V10.csv$Value[2]
```

I would like to replace the V**01** by a variable, so that I can use a loop.

Below is what I try so far:

```
k <- 10
test0 <- paste0("V",k)
test1 <- as.numeric(paste0("V", k))
```

Which will theoretically allow me to access the same value as before by writing:

```
list.data$test0.csv$Value[2]
// Or
list.data$test1.csv$Value[2]
```

And use a loop by only changing the value of `k`.

But it does not work. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use `[[` for passing object names to extract an element from a `list`.

```
 test0 <- paste0("V",k, ".csv")
 list.data[[test0]]$Value[2]
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! Could you explain the `[[]]` vs the `$` ?

Comment: @JustineVandendorpe  According to `?"[["` `Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does`